# Sort table after ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to sort a table with the code from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sort_table.asp).

But the table is loading after an Ajax call and in the JS I can't get the table, although I can get the table class.

Below is a simplified code.

I omit the sorting code, because the problem is before that (see Temporary checking code).

Anyone can tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```js
$(document).on('click', '[id^="sortTable-"]', function() {
  var Exploted = this.id.split("-");
  var n = Exploted[1];
  var WhichTable = Exploted[2];

  //Temporary checking code
  var XX = $("#" + WhichTable).attr('class');
  alert(XX);
  //OK, I get the table class (TheTableClass), meaning that the table is being detected, even though it was loaded after the initial page load (with Ajax)

  var theTable = $('#' + WhichTable);
  var rows = theTable.rows;

  if (theTable.lenght) {
    alert("ok, table detected, and it has " + rows + " rows");
  } else {
    alert("Table NOT detected! Has rows? " + rows);
  }
  //in the previous if statement, I get "Table NOT detected! Has rows? undefined"

  //End of Temporary checking code

  //here the sorting code from
  //https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sort_table.asp
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="TheTableClass" id="MyTableId">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th id="sortTable-0-MyTableId">Name</th>
      <th id="sortTable-1-MyTableId">Surname</th>
      <th id="sortTable-2-MyTableId">Age</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Tom</td>
      <td>32</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Alex</td>
      <td>Jerry</td>
      <td>28</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Getting the table element is much simpler using `$(this).closest('table')`. Within the handler function `this` is the `<th>` the event occurred on

Comment: @charlietfl thanks. I will use your suggestion. As you can see, in the sortable td I include the table id. That is because I have several tables. With you suggestion I can get rid of that. Thanks

Comment: Also Move the TH to a THEAD and then sort the TBODY

Answer (score 1):

You are spelling `length` wrong here `theTable.lenght`. This should be `theTable.length`. Other than that i don't see any other issue.

Comment: I do not know how to express myself without imprecations. That was the point, thank you!. Five hours with this...
I will delete this post in a while to keep this site clean. It is of no use to have a "question" like this.

Thanks again.